# Cant display text from database

Tags: php, database

I have like a news feed on my site. You can post news on a post.php site, and when you post a news the news come up on this news.php. The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
element {
color: black;
}


body {
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(bgn1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
 }
.news {
font-family: Rough_Typewriter;
font-size: 36px;
 }
 </style>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>iWrite</title>
 <meta name="view" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="keywords" content="">

 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <h1 class="news">iWrite</h1>
 <p>
 <hr>
  <p>
 <p>
    <p>
    <p>
  <p>
   <p>
  <p>
  <p>
   <p>
  <a href='post.php'>Want to post a text?</a>
  <?php

   //connect

   mysql_connect("myserver","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("databasename") or die(mysql_error());

    //query the database
    $getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_query());

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews))
     {

//get data
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body'];
$date = $row['date'];

echo "
<b>$title posted on $date</b><br>
";

echo nl2br($body);

echo "<hr>
";

    }



    ?>
```

But when it displays it on the index.html site it just echo out $title posted on $date....
Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a PHP file extension if you're embedding PHP code you want to be parsed. If you need to use .html, try using `mod_rewrite` in your .htaccess.

Comment: He is doing that: «the news come up on this news.php»

Comment: He said that this current file name is "news.php"!

Comment: Check the last line of his question:

But when it displays it on the **index.html** site it just echo out $title posted on $date.... Please help me!

Comment: Yep, just saw that, too. Sorry. @David, are you doing this on index.html or news.php?

Comment: Try saving it as `index.php`.

Comment: Go for the easy test. Stick `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` anywhere on your page. If you get the phpinfo dump then PHP is working otherwise I'd agree that the PHP on that page is not being parsed.

Comment: Another question: on www.youngcreativity.se - you see that the news show up. How can I put all the news in a cool rounded box?

Answer (score 0):

You should not echo variables like that in PHP.
Keep them out of the string

```
echo "<b>". $title ." posted on ". $date ."</b><br />"
```

Also:
It's bad practice to use `or die()` since this kills the script.
Use proper error handling instead.

Comment: Well your answer is bad practice as well. Don't use the concatenation operator with echo use a comma. i.e. `echo '<b>', $title, ' posted on ', $date, '</b><br />';`

Comment: @Mike may i ask why it is considered a bad practice? Is there any vulnerability on this?

Comment: @itachi - If you use the concatenation operator PHP will create a new temporary string variable, concatenate everything into it then echo the temporary variable. There's no need for any of those operations if all you are doing is echoing so just use a comma to echo the values immediately.